# Issue with import in Pycharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm

Why is it that when I type `import requests` in Pycharm that the code goes grey and shows an error?  I thought that adding importing modules in this way was standard

Comment: Have you [installed the requests module](http://askubuntu.com/questions/504068/how-to-install-requests-module-for-python3)?

Comment: try to install `requests` using pip, then import it.

Comment: I just installed requests using pip.  I've got Sublime Text and Pycharm open at the same time for the file.  When I write `import requests` in Sublime Text, all good.  Still when i write that in Pycharm it goes grey as soon as I type the last character.
When I type the code in ST and save it, it is then displayed in Pycharm without an error.  Until I delete the code and re-write it, and then I goes grey again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code going grey is the way that Pycharm has to tell you that the import is not used. It is not an error, but a warning saying that your import statement is not necessary (until you use it later in your code, of course).

You can customise this behaviour on Pycharm, through Preferences -> Editor -> Inspections.